# How to retrieve DateTime from prisma?

Tags: javascript, mysql, prisma

this is boardingFinished property

```
 boardingFinished   DateTime? @db.Date
```

How should i retrieve it from prisma?
I have a map function returning to me the selected properties, and i'm retrieving `boardingFinished` as

```
new Date(x.boardingFinished).toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')
```

But it's one day off.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Is there a difference in timezone involved ?

Comment: `x.boardingFinished` should be a `Date` already. Why do you use `new Date(...)` on it?

Comment: Check what format you are storing it on db, I mean GMT/UTC, then you need to convert it accordingly . We used momentjs for this conversation